# Pass parameters with different amount of variables to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create function that would take a random amount of parameters some defined, others not.
So I have this search function that would sometimes take all of the arguments, but sometimes just url, query and authHeader.

I did study about *arg, **kwards, but AFAIK they did not suit in this case.
Or do I *always* have to give them some value in my case, for example "null"? But that means I need to assign a value to variable and could not just *pass* it that time?

```
def search(url, query, resultLimit, resultInfoSize, authHeader):
searchRequest = session.post(url + '/services/search?q=' + query + '&num=' + resultLimit + '&datalinesToReturn='+ resultInfoSize, headers=authHeader)
searchData = searchRequest.json()
return searchData
```

Any opinion much appreciated.

## Update

as @Jerrybibo kindly stated I got my aswer:

So adding if condition in the function was what I was looking for. Changing the default values inside the function *if* on call none are provided.

```
def search(url, query, resultLimit, authHeader, resultLimit=None, resultInfoSize=None):
if resultLimit == None: resultLimit='50'
if resultInfoSize == None: resultInfoSize=''
searchRequest = session.post(url + '/services/search?q=' + query + '&num=' + resultLimit + '&datalinesToReturn='+ resultInfoSize, headers=authHeader)
searchData = searchRequest.json()
return searchData
```

Comment: Why didn't *arg suit in your case?

Comment: Can you use default parameter values, i.e. `def search(url, query, authHeader, resultLimit=None, resultInfoSize=None):`? This would require `authHeader` to come before the default-parameters, though.

Comment: @user8035311 Because im trying to avoid declaring any variable I dont need to use that time. If im using the arg `def search(elvisUrl, query, authHeader, arg_1, arg_2):`
I would still have to declare them in *main* `args = ("0", "0")` (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question, I believe one way of working around this is to have several of your function parameters set to default sentinel values (usually `None`; use whichever default value makes sense in your scenario) so that you do not *have to* pass the values on function call; and if you do pass them, they get processed just like normal parameters. Your function definition would look like this:

```
def search(url, query, authHeader, resultLimit=None, resultInfoSize=None):
```

Additionally, you may have to change your `searchRequest` definition in the function in the event that `resultLimit` or `resultInfoSize` is `None`.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that but problem is that it wont allow "None(type)" so something is still wrong here. Or it just doesn't allow the NoneType to go in the url..

`def search(url, query, authHeader, resultLimit=None, resultInfoSize=None):`
with calling it:

`results = search(webUrl, kQuery, authHeader)`

-> TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Comment: @mudstec I mentioned in the answer that you will probably have to change your `searchRequest` definition. Use an `if` conditional or something like that to filter the `None` out.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now.

Comment: @mudstec If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to the answer score.